# Adding/removing notebook pages in PyGTK/GTK on the fly

Tags: gtk, pygtk

How to refresh a notebook on the fly?

I have an application which is supposed to have various number of
pages according to the data in the underlying model. In order to
synchronize the appearance of the Notebook I'd like to refresh it
every time a row is added/deleted from the model.

I've tried this:

```
    ...
    def get_pagebox(self, label)
        ...
        return pagebox
    def _reinit(self):
        for child in self.notebook.get_children():
            self.notebook.remove(child)
        for label in self.get_labels():
            self.notebook.append(self.get_pagebox(label), label)
        self.notebook.queue_draw_area(0,0,-1,-1)
    ...
```

It removes the old pages, but fails to append new ones. What could be
the problem and how do you think this could be done?

Comment: `notebook` tag removed as part of the [2012 cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks fine. Did you try doing an explicit `show()` on the widgets after adding them?

Answer (score 4):

You should just call `show_all()` on the notebook after adding the new pages. All widgets created by GTK+ are initially hidden. The `queue_draw_area` call shouldn't be necessary.